# Cannot operate on a closed database

Tags: python, sqlite

I got this error, and I have no idea why. I tried to remove the db close code and it got no error but is it ok if I didn't close the database?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hp/Downloads/SimpleCoin-master/SimpleCoin-master/simpleCoin/recent.py", line 55, in <module>
    st()
  File "C:/Users/hp/Downloads/SimpleCoin-master/SimpleCoin-master/simpleCoin/recent.py", line 31, in st
    tran()
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database.
```

Here is my code

```
import sqlite3, time
from datetime import datetime


    def st():
        with sqlite3.connect("newone1.db") as db2:
            cursor1 = db2.cursor()
            # create table
            cursor1.execute('''
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions(
                private_k VARCHAR(100) NOt NUll,
                sender_k VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                receiver_k VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                c_amount INTEGER NOT NULL,
                dNt TEXT NOT NULL);
                ''')
            # insert values to table from user input
    
            pri_key = input('Sender Private Key: ')
            pub_key = input('Sender Public Key: ')
            r_pub_k = input('Receiver Public Key: ')
            c_amount = input('Amount: ')
            dt_for = datetime.now().strftime("%B %d, %Y %I:%M%p")
            cursor1.execute(""" 
                INSERT INTO transactions(private_k, sender_k, receiver_k, c_amount, dNt)
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)   
                """, (pri_key, pub_key, r_pub_k, c_amount, dt_for))
            db2.commit()
            # print("Data entered successfully")
            db2.close()
    
    
    def tran():
        private_key = input("Enter your private key number: ")
        with sqlite3.connect("newone1.db") as db2:
            cursor1 = db2.cursor()
    
        sql_cmd = 'SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE private_k={}'.format(private_key)
        cursor1.execute(sql_cmd)
        for row in cursor1.fetchall():
            pri_key = row[0]
            pub_key = row[1]
            r_pub_k = row[2]
            c_amount = row[3]
            dt_for = row[4]
            # print(pri_key)
            print('-------------------------------')
            print("From:", pub_key)
            print("To:", r_pub_k)
            print("Amount: ", c_amount)
            print("Date and Time: ", dt_for)
            print('-------------------------------')
    
    
    st()
    tran()
```

Comment: In `tran`, `cursor.execute` needs to be _indented_ to be inside the `with` statement, because the `with` statement will close the connection when it is exited.

Comment: i dont get it sir

Answer (score 0):

I'm just expanding the comment by @snakecharmerb. Credit there.

The `with` statement is connecting to the database and storing that connection in the `db2` variable. When the `with` statement's scope ends, `db2` is destroyed and the connection is closed. In python, a scope is ended by unindenting. So your connecting is being closed before you `sql_cmd = 'SELECT...` line. You need it to stay in scope until after your `fetchall` is finished.

So this should work better:

```
    def tran():
        private_key = input("Enter your private key number: ")
        with sqlite3.connect("newone1.db") as db2:
            cursor1 = db2.cursor()
    
            sql_cmd = 'SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE private_k={}'.format(private_key)
            cursor1.execute(sql_cmd)
            for row in cursor1.fetchall():
                pri_key = row[0]
                pub_key = row[1]
                r_pub_k = row[2]
                c_amount = row[3]
                dt_for = row[4]
                # print(pri_key)
                print('-------------------------------')
                print("From:", pub_key)
                print("To:", r_pub_k)
                print("Amount: ", c_amount)
                print("Date and Time: ", dt_for)
                print('-------------------------------')
```